# Verificar se existem registros em lista no entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, query, linq

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
var ret = Monitoramento.List
            .Include(p => p.CD)
            .ThenInclude(p => p.CargaEntrega)
            .ThenInclude(p => p.CargaEntrega.Motorista)
            .ThenInclude(p => p.CargaEntrega.Veiculo)
            .ThenInclude(p => p.CargaEntrega.Entregas)
            .ThenInclude(p => p.CargaEntrega.Entregas.Select(s => s.Cliente))
            .ThenInclude(p => p.CargaEntrega.Entregas.Select(s => s.NotasFiscais))
            .GetQuery()
            .Where(
                p => !p.IsDeleted
                && (p.Data >= dateInicio && p.Data <= dateFinal)
                && (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(filtro.motoristaId) ? 
                    p.CargaEntrega.Motorista.Id.ToString() == filtro.motoristaId : 1 == 1)
                && (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(filtro.unidadeNegociosId) ? 
                    p.CD.Id.ToString() == filtro.unidadeNegociosId : 1 == 1)
                && (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(filtro.status) ? 
                    statusBuscado.Contains(p.StatusMonitoramento) : 1 == 1)
                && (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(filtro.nroTransporte) ? 
                    "" + p.CargaEntrega.Entregas.FirstOrDefault().NroTransporte == filtro.nroTransporte : 1 == 1)
                && (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(filtro.uf) ? 
                    "" + p.CargaEntrega.Entregas.FirstOrDefault().Cliente.Estado == filtro.uf : 1 == 1)                    
             )
            .Select(MonitoramentoDto.ToDto)
            .ToArray();

        // Garantia de que os monitoramentos obedecem as duas regras:
        // Não exibe entregas que não possuem nota fiscal
        // Não exibe monitoramentos que não possuem entregas
        foreach (MonitoramentoDto itemMonitoramento in ret)
        {
            if(itemMonitoramento.Entregas.Length > 0)
            {
                List<EntregaDto> entregas = new List<EntregaDto>();
                foreach (EntregaDto entrega in itemMonitoramento.Entregas)
                {
                    if(entrega.NotaFiscal.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        entregas.Add(entrega);
                    }
                }

                if (entregas.Count > 0)
                {
                    itemMonitoramento.Entregas = entregas.ToArray();
                    monitoramentoLimpo.Add(itemMonitoramento);
                }

            }
        }
```

A intenção é remover o `foreach` abaixo e adicioná-lo diretamente a consulta da variável `ret`. O `foreach` remove as entregas que não possuem notas fiscais, sendo que NotaFiscal é uma `IList` dentro da `IList` de Entregas.

Alguma ideia de como posso otimizar esta consulta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que pude observar, somente coloque essa condição dentro do seu `where`:

```
&& p.SeuModelAteChegarNasEntregas.Entregas.Any()
```

Após isso, ele só irá trazer os que tenham entregas.

Você pode adicionar após o `select`:

```
.Select(MonitoramentoDto.ToDto).Where(m => m.Any(a => a.Entregas.Any()))
```

**Edit1:**

Tendo uma lista de entregas:

```
Entregas.Where(m => m.NotasFiscais.Any())
```

Aí você pode usar ela no primeiro exemplo que coloquei ali em cima.

Comment: Na verdade o que eu preciso é verificar se a lista de notas fiscais dentro da lista de entregas (de cada entrega) possuem ao menos 1 registro, as que não tiverem nada ou forem nulas não deve trazer, seria algo como SELECT *
  FROM Entrega
  Left outer join NotaFiscal on Entrega.Id = NotaFiscal.Entrega_Id
  where NotaFiscal.Id is not null

Comment: atualizei meu comentário, olha aí

Comment: Fechou é isso mesmo, valeu obrigado!